# TYPO3 Ckeditor Error (".." and "//" is not allowed in path) on saving

Tags: typo3, ckeditor

I have TYPO3 11.5.28

When I save a tt_content (textpic) using ckeditor I get this error:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Exception\InvalidPathException
File /<h2>word</h2> <p>Lorem is not valid (".." and "//" is not allowed in path).
```

This occurs when I write a single word within a first line tag.
es:

```
<h2>word</h2>... etc ..etc
```

But this doesn't happen when I write

```
<h2>word anotherword</h2> ... etc ... etc
```

how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0):

What does your CKeditor config look like?

Is  it only happening for textpic, or all CTypes?

Any custom or public extensions installed that modify CKeditor behavior OR the textpic CType (TCA)?

To me it sounds a bit like configuration is trying to cast the RTE field to parse images/file paths; maybe a plugin/extension that tries to allow inline images in the RTE?

Comment: I use my own configuration but it also happens if I use the default typo3 one. I use rte_ckeditor_image as plugin. it happens only for textpic

Comment: @MarioProject is it reproducible also in the most recent TYPO3 11 patch release?